# How to load image dataset in python? What does 'Websocket ping timeout' mean?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

I use python3(anaconda) in window7.

For studying deep learning, I downloaded image dataset.
(http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~andyz/downloads/MMU2IrisDatabase.zip)
image dataset: 995 images, 65.4MB.

But, loading dataset, I faced 2 problems.

First, I tried solution_1.

```
# Solution_1

import os
import numpy as np
import zipfile
from PIL import Image
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
from scipy import misc

def import_caltec100(dataset = 'MMU2IrisDatabase.zip'): # file: 'MMU2IrisDatabase.zip'
    X_array = np.empty((1, 238, 320, 3))
    Y_list = list()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(dataset) as caltec:
        for i, file in enumerate(caltec.namelist()):
            if file.split('.')[-1] == 'bmp' and len(file.split('/')[2].split('.')[0]) == 6:
                img_array = misc.imread(BytesIO(caltec.read(file)))
                X_array = np.vstack((X_array, img_array.reshape(1, 238, 320, 3)))
                Y_list.append(int(file.split('/')[2].split('.')[0][:2]))

            elif file.split('.')[-1] == 'bmp' and len(file.split('/')[2].split('.')[0]) == 7:
                img_array = misc.imread(BytesIO(caltec.read(file)))
                X_array = np.vstack((X_array, img_array.reshape(1, 238, 320, 3)))
                Y_list.append(int(file.split('/')[2].split('.')[0][:3]))

    X_array = X_array[1:]
    Y_array = np.array(Y_list)
    return X_array, Y_array
```

It returns 'Websocket ping timeout after 119995ms' in jupyter.

```
# Solution_2

X_array = np.empty((1, 238, 320, 3))
Y_list = list()
for file in os.listdir('MMU2IrisDatabase'):
    if file.split('.')[-1] == 'bmp' and len(file.split('.')[0]) == 6:
        img_array = misc.imread('MMU2IrisDatabase/{}'.format(file))
        X_array = np.vstack((X_array, img_array.reshape(1, 238, 320, 3)))
        Y_list.append(int(file.split('.')[0][:2]))

    elif file.split('.')[-1] == 'bmp' and len(file.split('.')[0]) == 7:
        img_array = misc.imread('MMU2IrisDatabase/{}'.format(file))
        X_array = np.vstack((X_array, img_array.reshape(1, 238, 320, 3)))
        Y_list.append(int(file.split('.')[0][:3]))

X_array = X_array[1:]
Y_array = np.array(Y_list)
```

There was no error, but it took too long(Wall time: 32min 43s).

Please solve my difficulties.

First, I want to know what 'Websocket ping timeout after 119995ms' means.
Second, Is there any better way to load image dataset?

Comment: it's not a tensorflow problem. you should use a proper tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your 2nd solution is that you recreate the whole array all the time. What I do is something like this:

```
img_data = []
for file in os.listdir(dir):
    if file.endswith('bmp'):
       img_data.append(misc.imread(os.path.join(dir, file)).reshape(238, 320, 3))
X_array = np.array(img_data, dtype=np.float32)
```

Anyways if you want to know what is taking the program so long, you should try the profiler (https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html).